# The space of collars of a manifold is contractible

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

> Theorem: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary $\partial M$. Let $e_0,e_1 : \partial M\times [0,1]\rightarrow M$ be collars of $M$, i.e. $e_i$ are embeddings such that $e_i(x,0)=x$ for each $x\in \partial M$. Then $e_0$ and $e_1$ are isotopic through embeddings.

For some reason, it is difficult to find a clear proof of this in the literature, despite it being a fundamental result underlying the entirety of, say, cobordism theory and surgery. The only clear reference I could find was buried in Cerf's dissertation, in French. In Q&A style, I submitted my take on a proof as an answer. Are there any holes here? If so, I would appreciate any help to fix my proof.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can "scale" $e_0$ and $e_1$ by smooth functions $h_0,h_1:\partial M \rightarrow (0,1]$ such that the embeddings $e_i'(x,t)=e_i(x,h_i(x)t)$ have the same image in $M$. For example, we can do this by first shrinking $e_1$ until its image is properly contained in the image of $e_0$, then shrinking $e_0$ to match their images. $e_0',e_1'$ are isotopic to the original pair, so we may assume that $e_0$ and $e_1$ have the same image in $M$.

The composition $e'=e_0^{-1} \circ e_1$ gives an automorphism of $\partial M\times [0,1]$ which is the identity on $\partial M \times \{0\}$. Define an isotopy $h:\partial M \times [0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow \partial M \times [0,1]$ by $h(x,t,s)=(e'(x,ts)_{\partial M},(1-s)t+se'(x,t)_{[0,1]})$, where the subscript $_{\partial M}$ denotes the projection $(x,t)\mapsto x$ onto $\partial M$ and similarly for $_{[0,1]}$. The fact that this is an isotopy follows since $e'(x,ts)_{\partial M}$ gives a flow on $\partial M$, and any two increasing self-embeddings of $[0,1]$ are isotopic.  This sets up an isotopy between $e_0^{-1}\circ e_1$ and the identity. Consequentally, $e_0$ and $e_1$ are isotopic.

Comment: The hole in the proof is the first part where you reduce to maps with the same image.

Comment: Why is it a problem? I don't see why I cannot do this. If I can scale the second map to land in the image of the first, by scaling it sufficiently its preimage through the first map will have connected fibers over $\partial M$, so we should be able to scale it up again (or shrink $e_0$) to match them. What goes wrong?

Comment: I am not saying that it is impossible, the problem is actually proving the claim.  (You can easily make one collar to be contained in the other, that's not the problem.)  It is harder than you think, just try to write down details. As a mental picture, consider a properly embedded smooth hypersurface $S$ in $R^n$, lying in the upper half-space $R^n_+$. If $S$ were the graph of a smooth function, it is indeed easy to (properly) isotope $S$ to the hypersurface $x_n=1$ rel. boundary of $R^n_+$. However, $S$, typically, is not a graph. This is similar to the issues arising ...

Comment: ... in naive attempts to prove smooth Schoenflies theorem in $R^4$ (where it is still open). Namely, see if you can (similarly to your argument) "prove" that every smoothly embedded 3-sphere in $R^4$ bounds a smooth ball: Equivalently, that can be isotoped to the unit sphere.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. If we require the collars to intersect $\partial M$ transversely, then at least for small enough values for $t$, the pullback into the other collar will define the graph of a function, right? It should go like $(f(x,t),r(x)t)$ for some positive real-valued function r(x). In my head it should be like the proof using morse functions of the existence of collar neighborhoods.